# DataType of a Column in DataTable

Tags: datatable, sqldatatypes

I am creatin a datatable in C#,(sharepoint 2010). I want to add a column of datatype date having format "dd/mm/yyyy"

Can anyone tell me how to define a datatype for this column?

I tried this:

```
//SharePoint2010
    table.Columns.Add("Start Date", typeof(DateTime));

    To display in dd/MM/yyyy
    DateTime sdt = DateTime.Parse(req["Start_x0020_Date"].ToString());

    row["Start Date"] = sdt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

But i am getting the output as dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS

Please help i want the output as dd/MMyyyy

Comment: Why don't you just use `DateTime`?

Comment: @NeilKnight can you please mention How? for a DataTable,suppose if the name of the column is date and name of DataTable is Emp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `DateTime` column to the `DataTable` and later you may format it to "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

```
DataTable dataTable=new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("date",typeof(DateTime));
```

EDIT: 
No need to use DateTime column type to store string. Use string column type.

```
 table.Columns.Add("Start Date");
 ..
 table.Rows.Add(sdt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
 //OR
 row["Start Date"] = sdt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```